# I want to send emails to a number of email addresses that varies

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am encountering the following problem:
I am sending an email per row from my spreadsheet for a number of rows which varies every week. Now the script only works for me, if i exactly define the number of rows that will have values.

I don't know how to substitute numRows = 1 with a function that checks getlastRow.

Here is the script I am using:

```
/**
 * Sends emails with data from the current spreadsheet.
 */
function sendEmails() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID");
  var current = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet");
  var startRow = 4; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 1; // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B5
  var dataRange = current.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 1);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column
    var message = row[1]; // Second column
    var subject = 'Stock values end of month';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!